# How to view source code of contracts in etherscan

Tags: ether, etherscan

I'm doing a hobby project and as far as i know source code of contracts published in Etherscan are publicly available and can be seen here like for Tether but some tokens only have the options to query their codes. Is there any way to see their source code too

**As in this picture source code available**

[image: Source code available]

> As in this picture source code not available

[image: Source Code not available]

I'm curious to know is there anyway to know what was the source code of this contract

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 contract screens on etherscan, one where you can interact with the contract and one where you view the source code.

You are on the one where you are interacting.
So all you need to do is click on the contract address on the top right like here:
[image]

Then you will see the contract tab below here to view the source code:
[image]

Comment: See this here, I'm on contract page https://etherscan.io/address/0x55fe1a2750594a8C06f503A2F48Ae64Df24fEcdB#code

Comment: SO the only thing this means is that the contract owner has not verified the contract. There isn't a way on etherscan to then view the contract. You can decompile the bytecode but it wont give an accurate full view of the code.